# Using DatePicker via TypeScript import and Webpack2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, antd

I'm trying to test Ant Design components within a `TypeScript + React + Webpack2` setup.

I'm importing the `DatePicker` component manually, so that webpack can grab it out and build it into my bundle.

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as moment from "moment";
import DatePicker from 'antd/lib/date-picker';
import "antd/lib/date-picker/style/css";

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return <DatePicker value={moment(new Date())} format={"YYYY.mm.dd."}/>;
    }
}
```

But when I try to run the compiled code in the browser, the component won't render, as the particular import compiles into this final code.

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var React = __webpack_require__(4);
var moment = __webpack_require__(0);
var date_picker_1 = __webpack_require__(287);
__webpack_require__(289);
var TestComponent = (function (_super) {
    __extends(TestComponent, _super);
    function TestComponent() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    TestComponent.prototype.render = function () {
        return React.createElement(date_picker_1.default, { value: moment(new Date()), format: "YYYY.mm.dd." });
    };
    return TestComponent;
}(React.Component));
exports.default = TestComponent;
```

Please note the `date_picker_1.default` reference, which is `undefined`, and causes the error.

Why is this happening? It shouldn't call `default` on the imported object, just use it, as it is the `DateTimePicker` component itself.

I have the following setup. TypeScript compiles into `es5` using `commonjs` module system. This is done by the `awesome-typescript-loader` webpack loader. The rest should be done by webpack itself.

Answer (score 0):

The DateTimePicker does have a default export (see [lib/date-picker/index.js](https://unpkg.com/antd@2.9.1/lib/date-picker/index.js) at the bottom), but when TypeScript compiles it to a commonjs module there is some sort of problem.

Webpack 2 handles ES modules out of the box, so you should leave the imports to webpack instead. Simply change the compiler option `module` to `es6`.

```
"module": "es6"
```

You can change that without having to change your target, so it still outputs `es5` but doesn't use commonjs modules. From the [TypeScript - Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> ► "ES6" and "ES2015" values may be used when targeting "ES5" or lower.